# Matlab Multiple Hidden Layer Neural Network with GUI?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I've successfully made a neural network that does what I want using the nftool GUI. But now I want to see if I can raise the quality by adding more hidden layers, and I don't see clues that that's an option. Is there an easier way to do this than writing the code line by line?

Comment: What does this have to do with a GUI?

Comment: nftool is a tool with its own GUI - boxes to fill with things like how many nodes in the hidden layer, drop down menus for things like which training algorithm to use, and buttons for different options of what to do next.

Comment: Oh Ok I see that now in your post. I have gone ahead and removed the matlab GUI tag though since it's not related directly to the MATLAB gui